# Unusually USB filesystem behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, partitioning, filesystems

To start off I'm using linux and I found something quite interesting on one of my USBs. Long ago, I made a new partition table in the USB, both FAT32, 8gb a piece (16gb in Total) - Installed a linux ISO on one, and used the other for storage.

So one day I wiped it clean, with a new format, and tried writing files onto it. Said it could handle about 15.2 GB, which sounded right.

Tried moving about 14GB of data to it, and it had trouble writing - Always said not enough space even though the USB said it had way more.

So of course my programmer instincts kick in, and I remount the usb, and start gluing some quick python to try to find the partition size I was dealing with.

```
from collections import namedtuple
def disk_usage(path):
  """Return disk usage statistics about the given path.

  Returned valus is a named tuple with attributes 'total', 'used' and
  'free', which are the amount of total, used and free space, in bytes.
  """
  st = statvfs(path)
  free = st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize
  total = st.f_blocks * st.f_frsize
  used = (st.f_blocks - st.f_bfree) * st.f_frsize
  return namedtuple('usage', 'total used free')(total, used, free)
```

(Found on stack overflow)

Surprise, surprise - I'm working with 8GB of data from `sdb1`
Then I guess I had the idea of mounting `sdb` by it's self.

Guess what I find.

I find a Read-Only decompressed ISO of linux, with all it's files still there.

So out of instinct; I tried `rm -rf *`, then with `sudo`.
None worked, so I tried switching ownership with `chown`, That worked.
So then I tried giving new permissions to read and write with `chmod` That didn't work. Even tried reformatting the drive, Ofcourse it reformatted - But the files are very much still there. So I have a few questions hopefully we can all figure out how to answer,

1) How can reverse the effects and return the USB to it's full 16/15GB into one partition again?

2) If this procedure can be done again - Can this "read-only" system possibly execute?

3) Since the partition tables should be over written, why are the files there?

Comment: Are you trying to write any particularly large files? The maximum file size for fat32 is 4GB.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to write any large files, but a large amount of data in small files.

Comment: What says your partition manager? Tried to wipe out the whole key contents using `dd` to write to `/dev/sdb`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear on certain key details; however, you should be aware that both partitioning a disk and creating a fresh filesystem ("formatting" the disk) leave *most* of the data on a disk intact, just "untethered" from any way to access individual files. If you search a disk sector-by-sector, you can recover old files from before a disk repartitioning or filesystem-creation operation. Tools like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) rely on this fact to enable recovery of old files. This is true of both traditional spinning-disk media and electronic media (USB flash drives and SSDs), although if you enable TRIM features on an SSD, the SSD may re-map and erase sectors, which makes data recovery harder.

Depending on the partition table types involved (MBR, GPT, or the Frankenstein's monster hybrid format used by most Linux distributions' `.iso` installers), the filesystem(s) involved, and what else was written to the disk, you could easily see enough of an older filesystem to be able to mount it; however, some of the data on an older filesystem would likely be destroyed.

My *suspicion* is that your USB drive is perfectly fine, and you've simply left the original partition table (which divides the disk in two equal parts) intact. You can examine and change the partition table with whatever partitioning software you like -- typically GParted, `parted`, `fdisk`, or `gdisk` in most Linux distributions, although there are others, too. Since you showed no output from any of these tools, I can't be sure of what the disk's current state is.

Comment: My normal parted commands had no effect, so I ended up zero'ing the drive and that worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

So I'm not sure about all my questions, but here's my own best shot.

- Firstly, to reverse the effects, simple run `dd if=/dev/zero of=sdX`
- Secondly... No idea why this happened.
- Thirdly, yes it is still executable from MBR.

Reformatting the partition table with the following commands had no effect on the clearing the files on sdX

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1

parted /dev/sdX mktable msdos

parted /dev/sdX mkpart primary partition_type 1 100%

wipefs -a /dev/sdX --force
```

Comment: Wiping the complete USB stick makes no sense unless he wants to make sure old sensitive data can't be recovered. In fact, it's a bad idea because it will decrease the lifespan of the stick slightly, but unecessarily. What he needs is a new partition table, see other answer.

Comment: Editted in the commands I used to reformat the usb originally that didn't work.